# Custom function which searches for tags in file always return null

Tags: android, null, file-read

I've created a custom function which should search a file for a specified tag, and return the value of it, like this:

Function call:

```
getSingleLineValue("tagname");
```

Found line in file:

```
<tagname>=tagvalue
```

Returned String:

```
tagvalue
```

Here is the code for the function:

```
public String getSingleLineValue(String tag) {
    // The value
    String value;
    // If the list of passed tags contains the wanted tag
    if(passedTags.contains(tag)) {
        // Close the readers
        close();
        // RESET EVERYTHING
        try {
            // Re-create the FileReader
            fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            // Re-create the BufferedReader
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            // Reset the passed tags array
            passedTags.clear();
            // Recall the function
            value = getSingleLineValue(tag);
            // Return the value
            return value;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            // Handle the exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        try {
            // The current line
            String line;
            // While the file has lines left
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                // If the current line contains a pair of tag marks ( < and > )
                if (line.contains("<") && line.contains(">")) {
                    // If the line contains the tag
                    if(line.contains(tag)) {
                        // Store the parts of the tag in an array (tag and value)
                        String[] tagParts = line.split("=");
                        // Get the value
                        value = tagParts[1];
                        // Return the value
                        return value;
                    } else {
                        // Get the passed tag
                        String passedTag = line.substring(1, line.indexOf(">") - 1);
                        // Add the tag to the passed tags array
                        passedTags.add(passedTag);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            // Handle the exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // If the tag wasn't found, return null
    return null;
}
```

The object called `file` is a simple `File` object with the path to the file I want to read. It's declared in the same class.

The objects called `fileReader` and `bufferedReader` is just what it sounds like. A `FileReader` and a `BufferedReader`, declared like this (also in the same class):

```
private FileReader fileReader;
private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
```

And in the constructor of the class:

```
fileReader = new FileReader(file);
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
```

The problem is that this function always return null, so when I call it, the above demonstration about how I want it to work would instead look something like this:

Function call:

```
getSingleLineValue("tagname");
```

Found line in file:

*Unknown (maybe this is the problem?)*

Returned String:

```
null
```

The problem might be something with the line, because when I print it, I don't get any message in the console, but I don't really know what could be wrong with it, if it's the problem.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out what was the problem. **It wasn't the function**, which actually worked fine, but **it was the file's encoding**.

I created a simple computer version and added the function to it, and printed all read lines, and found out that the file was read differently in the program than in Sublime Text (a text editor on the computer). A line which looked like this:

```
ABCDEFG
```

in the text editor, was read by the program like this:

```
A B C D E F G
```

So basically, it added a space between each character. I think the problem is with the file encoding, so the function works great itself.

**EDIT:** I solved the file encoding problem by using a FileInputStream and set it's encoding to "UTF-16LE", which was the correct encoding for my file, so the code above instead looked like this:

```
public String getSingleLineValue(String tag) {
    // The value
    String value;
    // If the list of passed tags contains the wanted tag
    if(passedTags.contains(tag)) {
        // Close the readers
        close();
        // RESET EVERYTHING
        try {
            // Re-create the FileInputStream
            fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);  // <----- Changed
            // Re-create the InputStreamReader
            inputReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInput, "UTF-16LE");  // <----- Changed
            // Re-create the BufferedReader
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);  // <----- Changed
            // Reset the passed tags array
            passedTags.clear();
            // Recall the function
            value = getSingleLineValue(tag);
            // Return the value
            return value;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            // Handle the exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        try {
            // The current line
            String line;
            // While the file has lines left
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                // If the current line contains a pair of tag marks ( < and > )
                if (line.contains("<") && line.contains(">")) {
                    // If the line contains the tag
                    if(line.contains(tag)) {
                        // Store the parts of the tag in an array (tag and value)
                        String[] tagParts = line.split("=");
                        // Get the value
                        value = tagParts[1];
                        // Return the value
                        return value;
                    } else {
                        // Get the passed tag
                        String passedTag = line.substring(1, line.indexOf(">") - 1);
                        // Add the tag to the passed tags array
                        passedTags.add(passedTag);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            // Handle the exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // If the tag wasn't found, return null
    return null;
}
```